# signup using retrofit and handle radiobutton & spinner

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

How to handle `RadioButton` and `Spinner` in user registration using retrofit.

`RadioButton` is user type (professional, Visitor) and `Spinner` is list having user type category how to pick data from both using retrofit for user registration .... need help

Design Screen
[image: Design Screen]

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.saadhashmi.docdirect.Interface.RetrofitClient;
import com.example.saadhashmi.docdirect.R;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class Signup_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinner;
    private EditText edit_username , edit_email , edit_firstname ,
            edit_lastname  , edit_Phone , edit_password , edit_retypePassword;
    private RadioGroup radiogroup;
    private RadioButton professional_btn , visitor_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_);
        Window window = getWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            window.setStatusBarColor(getColor(R.color.login_statusbar_color));
        }
        else {
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.login_statusbar_color));
        }

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ui_user_type);
        edit_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ui_username_signup);
        edit_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ui_email_signup);
        edit_firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ui_firstname_signup);
        edit_lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ui_lastname_signup);
        edit_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ui_password_signup);
        edit_Phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ui_phone_signup);
        edit_retypePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ui_retypePassword_signup);
        radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ui_radiogroup_signup);
        professional_btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ui_professional_radiobtn);
        visitor_btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ui_visitor_radiobtn);


        radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int option = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                switch (option)
                {
                    case R.id.ui_professional_radiobtn:
                        if (professional_btn.isChecked()){
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    case R.id.ui_visitor_radiobtn:
                        if (visitor_btn.isChecked()){
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                        }
                }
            }
        });






        findViewById(R.id.ui_signinaccount_text).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent move_login_screen = new Intent(Signup_Activity.this , Login_Activity.class);
                startActivity(move_login_screen);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.ui_signup).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                userSignup();
            }
        });

        List<String> select_user_type = new ArrayList<>();
        select_user_type.add(0 , "Select User Type");
        select_user_type.add("Doctor");
        select_user_type.add("Hospital");
        select_user_type.add("Clinic");
        select_user_type.add("Pharmacy");
        select_user_type.add("Blood Bank");
        select_user_type.add("Fitness Center");


        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item , select_user_type);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Select User Type")){

                }else {
                    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }



    private void userSignup(){


        String username = edit_username.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = edit_email.getText().toString().trim();
        String first_name = edit_firstname.getText().toString().trim();
        String last_name = edit_lastname.getText().toString().trim();
        String phone = edit_Phone.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = edit_password.getText().toString().trim();
        String confirm_password = edit_retypePassword.getText().toString().trim();



        if (username.isEmpty()){
            edit_username.setError("User Name is Required");
            edit_username.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            edit_email.setError("Enter a valid Email");
            edit_email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (first_name.isEmpty()){
            edit_firstname.setError("First Name is Required");
            edit_firstname.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (last_name.isEmpty()){
            edit_lastname.setError("Last Name is Required");
            edit_lastname.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (!Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches()){
            edit_Phone.setError("Enter a valid Phone NO.");
            edit_Phone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()){
            edit_password.setError("Password required");
            edit_password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.length() < 6){
            edit_password.setError("Password should be atleast 6 characters");
            edit_password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (!confirm_password.equals(password)){
            edit_retypePassword.setError("Error in Password matching please check");
            edit_retypePassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (confirm_password.isEmpty()){
            edit_retypePassword.setError("Retype password is required");
            edit_retypePassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance()
                .getApi().createUser(username , email , first_name , last_name , phone , password , confirm_password);
          call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                  try {
                      String s  = response.body().string();
                      Toast.makeText(Signup_Activity.this , s , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                  Toast.makeText(Signup_Activity.this , t.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: which api calling to registration.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from spinner:

```
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

To get data from Radio Button:

```
radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int option = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            switch (option)
            {
                case R.id.ui_professional_radiobtn:
                    if (professional_btn.isChecked()){
                        String value = professional_btn.getText();
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                case R.id.ui_visitor_radiobtn:
                    if (visitor_btn.isChecked()){
                        String value = visitor_btn.getText();
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

Pass these values to your retrofit call.

Comment: I've edited for the same. Please check and let me know.

Comment: how to pass these values to retrofit call.

Comment: pass it along with the other values you pass

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for retrofit post api..
make pojo class for user ..

```
public class User{


@SerializedName("firstName")
private String firstName;

@SerializedName("password")
private String password;


@SerializedName("email")
private String email;
public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public void setPassword(String password){
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}
public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}
```

}

make respone class for given by server it make pojo class..

```
public class ResponseData{

@SerializedName("response")
private String response;

@SerializedName("details")
private String details;

public void setResponse(String response){
    this.response = response;
}

public String getResponse(){
    return response;
}

public void setDetails(String details){
    this.details = details;
}

public String getDetails(){
    return details;
}
```

}

after define retrofit ..

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com"; // define your url..

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}


private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
```

}

make interface for api calling..

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@POST("registrion")
Call<ResponseData> userReg(@Body User user);
```

}

api calling into activity or fragmen..

```
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    User user=new User();
    user.setEmail("abcd@gmail.com");
    user.setPassword("123");
    user.setFirstName("Vikas");
    Call<ResponseData> dataCall=apiInterface.userReg(user);
    dataCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, Response<ResponseData> response) {
            if (response!=null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null){
                // show message
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseData> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

add below dependecy into app level gradle file..

```
   implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```